# Python code that finds the number of palindromes

Tags: python, equation, palindrome

I am very confused, I do not know what kind of equation I should make. I cannot think of anything other than 1 that satisfies this condition. Can you give me some guidance on how to write this code?

For example, let me enter 3 as the number n. From ((2 ^ n) -1) comes = 7. I need to find a 7-digit palindrome number like 1670761

Comment: Do you mean palindromes?

Comment: yes i edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```py
def len_x_palimdrome(x,f,start = ""):
    #f - a callable object taking one input and returning a bool
    nums = "0123456789"
    for i in nums:
        if x == 1:
            if f(int(start+i+start)):
                return(i)
        elif x == 2:
            if f(int(start+i*2+start)):
                return(i*2)
        else:
            a = len_x_palimdrome(x-2,f)
            if a != None:
                return(i+a+i)
    return(None)
```

The function takes in the length and a function lambda or whatever that will be used as a filter. Note that the function will return the lowest palindrome that fulfills the requirement(s) defined in the function.

Example filter function:

```py
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return False
    return n%7 == 0
```

In conclusion:

```py
print(len_x_palimdrome(2**3-1,f))
```

Comment: what should i print

Comment: @loveubaby you should print the output of len_x_palimdrome

Comment: yes i did it but it didn't work NameError: name 'x' is not defined

can you write the whole code as a whole. my english is not good so I have a hard time understanding. by the way, you are sooo smart.

Comment: Copy the first code block into your code directly, then write a second function, like the one in the second code block. @loveubaby

Comment: i wrote 
print(len_x_palimdrome(3,f)) then it printed 00700 but it should be 0007000 because 2^3-1=7 and it is number of digits

Comment: @loveubaby the argument is x not n. So you should do  print(len_x_palimdrome(2**3-1,f)). Ill update my anwser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant palindromes - words that read backward are the same as normally.

We can check if a string is a palindrome like this:

```python
def is_palindrome(string):
    return(string == string[::-1])
```

Then we can loop over all n-s in a range and check like this:

```python
for n in range(1000):
    if is_palindrome(str(2**n-1)):print(n,2**n-1)
```

Comment: Could you specify, what do you want in that case?

Comment: For example, let me enter 3 as the number n. From ((2 ^ n) -1) comes = 7. I need to find a 7-digit palindrome number like 1670761